# .gitignore not ignoring file that hasn't been added to the repo

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a file in my git repo that has never been comitted or added with
`git add`. But .gitignore doesn't seem to work. This file is called

> bit_train_[3].json

No previous commits contain this file.
In my .gitignore (same folder as this file) I added the line

> bit_train_[3].json

If I use `git status -u` it says

> Untracked files: bit_train_[3].json

Why is this file still visible?
I suspect that the brackets `[3]` in the file name might cause the issue but I'm unsure

There are other .json files that I want to keep in my repos so I can't use `*.json` in my gitignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets are special characters — they mean character lists and ranges. To make `git` interpret them literally in `.gitignore` escape them with backslashes:

```
bit_train_\[3\].json
```